# Internet Explorer doesn't render CSS occasionally

Tags: internet-explorer, css

On one of my computers, Internet Explorer occasionally "forgets" to load CSS and instead displays the page using just the HTML, which resembles Web pages from 1995 in Spry Mosaic...

If I click CTRL+Refresh, I still get the same ugly page.

However, deleting temporary internet files, then reloading the page, has worked the last few times.  That would make me think it is a caching issue, but then why doesn't CTRL+Refresh work?  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Internet Explorer 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:  C: Drive was out of disk space.

I realize that's the troubleshooting equivalent of making sure the toaster is plugged in.  :)
I know I should have checked this, but it's so easy to assume nowadays with 40GB+ hard drives that it's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue within Firefox and Google Chrome sometimes. I don't have any evidence, but I've always just contributed it to the **HTTP request for the CSS file failing or timing out**. A page refresh (F5 or Ctrl+F5) always seems to work.

This happens to me at Twitter more than anything else.

What is your definition of 'occasionally'? Is this occurring > 3 times a day? Does it occur on some websites and not on others? **Most importantly, what version of Internet Explorer are you running?**

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this kind of problems also occurs due to malware/spywares on your computer. Run a malware check using any of the free utility available & see if it gets fixed. [Ad-Aware](http://www.lavasoft.com/products/ad_aware.php)
is one of such programs which helps in removing spywares.