# Internet Explorer not loading third-party CSS

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css, rendering

I'm having some problems with a user's Internet Explorer.  It looks like it isn't loading CSS for sites properly.

For example here on Super User the front page seems to have loaded the fonts correctly, but has not loaded any of the [background images](http://sstatic.net/su/img/sprites.png) a defined in the CSS [hosted at `sstatic.net`](http://sstatic.net/su/all.css?v=609fabe2825d), and the question / answer scores are in little boxes.

And on [`guardian.co.uk`](http://guardian.co.uk) the Guardian logo is loaded fine from [`static.guim.co.uk`](http://static.guim.co.uk/static/91708/networkfront/images/guardian_logo.gif) (as is defined in the HTML directly, not in the site's CSS file). But the menu bar is not formatted like defined [in the CSS](http://static.guim.co.uk/static/91708/common/styles/wide/top-navigation-drop-down.css) from that same `static.guim.co.uk` domain: no grey background, no coloured font, different font.

All images seem to be fine when loading them directly. As far as I can see there is no proxy setup for IE. All renders fine in Google Chrome.

Windows is fully up to date.  Malwarebytes and Norton don't report any spyware problems.  Resetting IE settings doesn't fix the problems. Safe Mode doesn't improve anything.

Any suggestions?  Not using IE isn't a solution for this particular user.

Comment: How's [your hard drive space](http://superuser.com/questions/30043/internet-explorer-doesnt-render-css-occasionally/30923#30923)? Any chance you triggered some [compatibility view](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197)? Sure there's no *system wide* proxy settings --notably from some virus scanner or firewall software-- that IE is using (but other browsers are not)?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's a CSS issue, but I guess it's caused by the images being loaded from a different domain. Like superuser.com gets its images from `sstatic.com`, such as [the sprite that includes the logo](http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/img/sprites.png).

Hence: are you sure another browser on that same machine doesn't give the same problems? If another browser has that same issue, then it is probably caused by some virus scanner. If not, then maybe some security settings in IE?

(Note that the CSS is loaded from `sstatic.com` as well, so if other parts of the CSS seem to be honoured, then it must be specific to images, not to blocking third-party domains in general.)

Comment: Chrome is fine - am trying to teach user (Father in Law) to use that instead.

Looks to be IE loading remote images...

Comment: @Dan, or: Chrome might be using different proxy settings, if any. As far as I know IE always uses the system wide proxy settings (which some virus scanner might have changed into its own), while *maybe* Chrome is using something different -- or none at all. Some virus scanner might also be intercepting IE traffic some other way (without a proxy), oblivious about Chrome if that was installed after the virus scanner was installed? I am just guessing, not using Windows so I don't know really.

Comment: As above, Safe Mode doesn't improve anything. 

I've tried adding SuperUser to the trusted sites and turning those settings to "Low" - no response.

Remote images certainly seems to be the cause of the issue though.

(No idea when the issue arose as FiL didn't even see the problem until it was pointed out even though BBC news didn't look right!)

Comment: @Dan, aha, BBC News. That uses a different domain for its static content as well, like `http://static.bbc.co.uk/frameworks/barlesque/1.2.8/newnav/style/main.css` (and many more other domains). Any other examples? (If you're interested: see [the SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/) for the why.)

Comment: talktalk.co.uk, 
guardian.co.uk,  
www.theregister.co.uk/

Comment: @Dan, by the way: I doubt Safe Mode will change proxy settings, as *when* using a proxy that may very well be required to get onto the internet to start with. Guess Windows would not disable that then. Can IE actually fetch the Super User sprite directly?

Comment: @Dan, right, static images for talktalk.co.uk are hosted on a different domain too, like: http://media.talktalk.co.uk/sites/TalkTalk/Components/Static/Generic_Components/Top_Navigation_Bar/BG.png And the logo for The Guardian is on a different domain too: http://static.guim.co.uk/static/91708/networkfront/images/guardian_logo.gif Can IE fetch it directly?

Comment: All those links seem to be fine when going directly.

As far as I can see there is no proxy setup for IE.

Comment: @Dan, but: still, it could also not be fetching the CSS to start with. You wrote "seems to have loaded the fonts correctly", which I interpreted as: it must have taken those definitions from the CSS. But that might not be the case. Now, The Guardian's logo is not defined in the CSS, but in the HTML. Did IE show that on the web page? See [this screen capture](http://img.skitch.com/20100711-q4x98xpakcbnrm6dk8aunediuw.png) for what I mean.

Comment: @Dan, I'm away for a bit. As I guess comments are not read that well, please add some examples from these comments to your question, for later readers. If the guardion.co.uk logo is not showing on the normal page either, then I guess you can also change the title to read "Internet Explorer does not load third-party images" or something like that. Success!

Comment: Guardian Logo is loaded.  Menu bar is not formatted - no grey background.  No coloured font.  Different font.

Comment: @Dan, hmmm. Just in case you don't know: Chrome has a right-click option "Inspect element", which either shows you references to an image in the HTML itself (like show in my earlier screen capture), or if it's not in the HTML source then it must be defined in the CSS. Maybe it can help figure out what, and what not, is loaded by IE.

Comment: Ah, the menu bar colours and fonts are defined in [a CSS file](http://static.guim.co.uk/static/91708/common/styles/wide/top-navigation-drop-down.css) that's on a different domain. @Dan, I guess you can safely change the title to "Internet Explorer not loading third-party CSS" then...

Comment: Thanks Arjen.  HAve to leave this for a while as need to head out.

Comment: Wasn't able to look at this until now and it's still happening.

Comment: @Dan, I already merged most of your comments into your question. I hope you don't expect any further magic unless you give us something better to work with than *"it's still happening"...* Success!

Comment: Sorry Arjen, was wondering if we could stir more interest - the information provided is all we have - IE not loading remote CSS, other browsers are fine.  No proxy set up.  Safe Mode makes no difference.  Don't know what else to try and change.

Answer (score 1):

An idea anyway...

Try rebooting windows into Safe Mode with Networking, and then try IE with the add-ons disabled (the link is usually buried in the start menu under Programs->Accessories->System Tools).

If it works as expected then you know it's more than likely a 3rd party piece of software causing the problem (i.e.: an anti-malware program trying to 'protect' you. ;) ).

Comment: Tried, tested, failed.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not affecting everything, maybe try [Shift-refreshing](http://lifehacker.com/5574852/shift%252Brefresh-is-like-the-restart-button-for-web-sites) the sites that seem messed up.

Comment: Shift refresh has no impact.

Comment: As an aside: while many sites are not that smart, Super User et al actually ensure that server side changes are always downloaded by the browser. Many sites just refer to `some-name.css`, but Super User uses a unique version number which is changed whenever the HTML of the site is changed, forcing a browser to fetch the latest CSS. Like, today: `http://sstatic.net/su/all.css?v=609fabe2825d`.